# When to use t-test and Chi-squared test

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, t-test, chi-squared-test

I want to find correlation between `win_lose` and other columns starting from `ID` to `eki_id`. The data has 100k rows.

1. Which test should be used to find correlation between `win_lose` and other categorical(object) type columns [ID,X_MOD_1,X_MOD_2, X_MOD_3, CONST_ID, eki_id]?
2. Which test should be used to find correlation between `win_lose` and other  continuous numerical columns i.e. `X_MOD_var` ?

I know that chi-squared test is used for categorical to categorical, but in case categorical to continuous which one to use? I could not find a clear answer. This video says use logistic regression. https://youtu.be/E0eFZzI9Epo?t=479

[image]

Comment: Title says t-test; question asks about correlations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have  a 2 factor category independent variable and a continuous dependent variable then look at performing a t-test.  In this case you have a categorical independent variable and count data for the dependent variable, i.e. number of wins and the number of losses; thus the $\chi^2$ test is the better test.

If you have a continuous independent variable such as "X_mod_var" and a binary dependent output (Yes/No) as in your example, then a logistic regression can model the probability function.

Here is a good introduction text for statistical tests and R: http://rcompanion.org/handbook/

Comment: Thanks! I just have one more thing to clarify. When you say `logistic regression can model the probability function` ? do you mean it predicts the most correlated continuous independent variables  in the dataset ?

Comment: No, logistic regression will predict the probability of the event based on the input from the independent variables.  To determine the most correlated variable is similar to other regressions of adding and subtracting the different variables and analyzing how the model changes.

Comment: ok, lets say we just want to know the most correlated continuous column to `win_lose` how would we do that ? I do not understand `To determine the most correlated variable is similar to other regressions...` Sorry my stat is poor:(

Comment: Start with a your best guess of what the model should be, fit it and and then test the fit.  If if the fit is poor try adding additional terms or if the model is complicated remove a some terms and repeat the process of fitting it and testing how good the fit is.

Comment: ok. Thanks  a lot Dave2e!